# calculate effort to reach A sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 6.7

On Sonarqube 6.7, I found Effort to Reach A scale on Project Detail > Measure > Maintainability.

I can not find out how to calculate it. As seen on picture, The debt is 2h41min, while Effort to Reach A is 1h17 min. Then I check the detail of Effort to Reach A and calculate the debt, it is 1h18 min.

Does anybody know how to calculate effort to reach A? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjuuq.png)

Comment: The 1 minute difference could be an rounding error.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is not about rounding, I have other project where the effort to Reach A is rate A, when I click to see the detail, there are some files with debt. I check on Rating field and see the files with debt on Effort to Reach A is file with Rating less than A. So I assume maybe the debt that displayed is debt that need to be fixed to get A. I try to check the files and see debt per issues, but can not find the pattern. So I wonder if anybody know what's the formula to calculate effort to reach A?